# Can you please Clarify flutter for me?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

My Questions about flutter is  ( in android studio IDE):

1- in windows can i download iOS virtual mobile ?

2- flutter in windows can only support code for android apps? , and later the app will convert to iOS app and…etc ? , or How is the operation going?

3- can you in windows code for iOS apps Directly or the code is the same code in windows whatever it’s ios or android

Answer (score 0):

1. No unles you use a vm

2.no it supports all playforms

3. No the advantage of using flutte is that it uses a single codebase to deploy on different platforms.

If you are interested in building ios app from windows take a look at https://developer.apple.com/xcode-cloud/

Comment: I have one more question: can you in windows in flutter code ios apps directly? is flutter in windows let me code in whatever platform i want ?

Comment: no not from windows. For development of iOS app you will definitely need a Mac.. There are few options like you can rent a Mac cloud or build on cloud. Or use CI CD like code magic though